# Xcode allows me to define the same function twice without warnings

Tags: ios, xcode

Just ran into an issue in an iOS project where a delegate function wasn't being called. Couldn't work out why it wasn't triggered.

The function was in a UITableViewController subclass.

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Turns out I had added the function manually with my own code, but it already existed further down the source file as part of the auto-generated code from XCode.

XCode didn't seem to have an issue with the fact that the function existed twice in the same source file.

Why isn't XCode showing a warning for this?

Any way to configure it to show a warning for this case scenario?

**Edit:** I'm using XCode 4.5.2

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt. Still no warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure one of the methods isn't in a category? That would be legal as the category would override the subclass' method. I just tested using Xcode 4.5.2 and got an immediate warning when I tried to use the same method name twice.

Comment: No, the methods were both in the same section of the `@implementation` section of the class.. pretty much just separated by commented out auto-generated code

Comment: Even if I remove the commented bit and leave them one after the other, i still get no warning..

Comment: Tried creating a new project and I do get the warning.. weird.

Comment: Try putting some bogus code in one method, then the other - say one line that just says "xxx = 10;", then see if the compiler picks it up when you try to compile. If it does not, then the code is not active (its wrapped in a #if block or something). The editor is not always in sync with the compiler - I've been bit by this when I inadvertantly removed a "#endif" statement.